# How to add CollectionView to ViewController with storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uicollectionview

I have moved collectionView to my `ViewController`, created IBOutlet, established connection with `dataSource` and `delegate`, added protocols: `UICollectionViewDataSource`, `UICollectionViewDelegate`, `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, and also added methods:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:   (NSInteger)section
{
return 5;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
return 1;
}


- (AdImageCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
AdImageCell *cell = (AdImageCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AdImageCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.jpg"];

return cell;
}
```

I also created custom cell and add this to `viewDidLoad`:

```
   [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"AdImageCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AdImageCellIdentifier"];
```

But my problem here is that `numberOfItemsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` is only called, but not `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it will work if you  remove the `collectionView registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier` from the `viewDidLoad` method.

[collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: never gets called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044936/collectionviewcellforitematindexpath-never-gets-called)

Hope it will help you..

Comment: @dfasfasdfdfasdfasf make sure you have added prototype cell on your collection view in the storyboard and set class for this cell as `AdImageCell`

Comment: vitalyster, do I need add this to collectionView if I load cell from .xib?